# How do I implement words that are not in dictionary must shown with error?

Tags: c#, regex, linq, tokenize

this is a program where a dictionary is implemented with custom regex and it tokenize all every string that is input. Now I want that the strings that does not match with any of the regex must be shown in display with "not in grammar" line. I cannot come across with any type of solution.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string StringRegex = "\"(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\"";
    string IntegerRegex = @"[0-9]+";
    string CommentRegex = @"//.*|/\*[\s\S]*\*/";
    string KeywordRegex = @"\b(?:astart|ainput|atake|aloop|batcommand|batshow|batprint|batmult|batadd|batsub|batdiv|batif|batelse|batgo|batend|till|and)\b";
    string DataTypeRegex = @"\b(?:int|string)\b";
    string IdentifierRegex = @"[a-zA-Z]";
    string ParenthesisRegex = @"\(|\)";
    string BracesRegex = @"\{|\}";
    string ArrayBracketRegex = @"\[|\]";
    string PuncuationRegex = @"\;|\:|\,|\.";
    string RelationalExpressionRegex = @"\>|\<|\==";
    string ArthimeticOperatorRegex = @"\+|\-|\*|\/";
    string WhitespaceRegex = @" ";
    Dictionary<string, string> Regexes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"String", StringRegex},
        {"Integer", IntegerRegex },
        {"Comment", CommentRegex},
        {"Keyword", KeywordRegex},
        {"Datatype", DataTypeRegex },
        {"Identifier", IdentifierRegex },
        {"Parenthesis", ParenthesisRegex  },
        {"Brace", BracesRegex },
        {"Square Bracket", ArrayBracketRegex },
        {"Puncuation Mark", PuncuationRegex },
        {"Relational Expression", RelationalExpressionRegex },
        {"Arithmetic Operator", ArthimeticOperatorRegex },
        {"Whitespace", WhitespaceRegex }
    };

    string input;
    input = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

    var matches = Regexes.SelectMany(a => Regex.Matches(input, a.Value)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(b =>
            new
            {    
                Value = b.Value + "\n",
                Index = b.Index,
                Token= a.Key 
            }))
    .OrderBy(a => a.Index).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i + 1 < matches.Count)
        {
            int firstEndPos = (matches[i].Index + matches[i].Value.Length);
            if (firstEndPos > matches[(i + 1)].Index)
            {
                matches.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach (var match in matches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: If none of the regexps matches, isn't `var matches` *null* or empty?

Comment: No, if I input asdasdas then ever single character gets tokenized and displays as identifier, But I want it to be shown as "not in language" sort of error

Comment: But in this case, the `asdasdas` matches one of the regexes (`IdentifierRegex = @"[a-zA-Z]"`), and this is expected behavior. Please clarify.

Comment: Identifiers are single character such as a, b, c... but when I input asdasdas it doesn't take it as one whole string rather it shows a= identifier, s=identifier, d=identifier and so on, means it splits the string and shows one character at a time. I want that it takes asdasdas as one string and shows NOT IN GRAMMAR.

Comment: Then the regex should be changed to `IdentifierRegex = @"\b[a-zA-Z]\b";` and then `asdasdas` will not match and you will be able to test for empty. Check [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/KRo2DH)

Comment: Glad it helped, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identifier regex should be changed to

```
var IdentifierRegex = @"\b[a-zA-Z]\b";
```

Then, `asdasdas` will not match and you will be able to test for an empty result, eg.

```
if (matches.Count == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Not in grammar");    
else
{ ... }
```

See [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/KRo2DH).

Comment: Wiktor. If I ever implement this code on windows form and want to show the result in richtextBox. how would it be? 
richTextBox.Text = match.ToString(); isn't working

Comment: `if (matches.Count == 0)
       richTextBox.Text = "Not in grammar";`